# jTDS hangs reading response for specific sql query

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have looked for a solution to this everywhere. If this is not the right place forgive me but here it goes...

I am using jTDS 1.3.1 and SQL server 2014. I prepare a statement that is read only, scrollable. The query is moderately complex:

```
SELECT "equipmentid","locationid","vendorid","mfg","equipmentdescription","qty","cost","paymentdate" FROM "farnam"."Equipment" e0 LEFT JOIN "farnam"."Acceptance" e1 ON e0."currentcofa" = e1."cofaid" LEFT JOIN "farnam"."PaymentHistory" e2 ON e0."equipmentinvoiceid" = e2."parentinvoiceid" WHERE ("category" = ? AND "status" = ?)
```

It is a left join over three tables. Two parameters could be anything i.e [1,1].
If try to call `PrepraredStatement.execute()` it returns but the next call be it a commit or another execute hangs during `readFully` method.

Now if I just append one space to the query string it does not hang. If I proceed to append one space everytime to all my queries then it hangs again but for a different case with different string length (i.e by adding let say `paymentdate>'2015-10-19'`).

MS jdbc driver does not have this problem (all the queries go thru). I do not use any connection pools, I just get the connection, and perform prepare then execute.

Has anyone experienced something like this and what can be done if one is partial to jTDS.

Comment: If a select is hanging then it seems like a db locking issue.  What locking granularity do you use with jTDS and what locking granularity do you use with MS jdbc driver?

Comment: I checked for locking and in the application there are none and in the test case the above statement is the only one executing. In both cases connection is READ_COMMITED and the statement is TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear before -- what are the locking properties on the backend db?  Not the properties in the application layer.